# Can I disable a command while still allowing things to be mapped to it?

Tags: key-bindings

I'd like to be able to create the commands

```
nmap oo o
nmap oi o<Esc>
nmap OO O
nmap OI O<Esc>
```

but the problem is that `o` triggers immediately and the second character ends up in Insert mode. `nnoremap o <nop>` doesn't fix things.

Can I "disable" the `o` command while still allowing it to be mapped?

Obviously I could just use a leader mapping, but I figure I might as well try and go ham with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run

```
nmap o <nop>
nnoremap oo o
nnoremap oi o<Esc>
nnoremap OO O
nnoremap OI O<Esc>
```

Comment: Thanks! I had the `noremap` stuff backwards. Although I'm already getting used to `<leader>o` and `<leader>O`...

Answer (score 3):

I feel like you mappings are designed to create black lines.  This is [a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2565531/438329) [common](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6765211/438329) [task](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16359878/438329) here are some quick mappings to put in your `vimrc` file.

```
nnoremap <silent> [<space> :pu! _<cr>:']+1<cr>
nnoremap <silent> ]<space> :pu _<cr>:'[-1<cr>
```

If you prefer a plugin then I suggest Tim Pope's [unimpaired.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1590). Which supplies these mappings, but will also take a count. The plugin also has many other nice mappings.